# Open Lotus Notes mail page without sending from .NET

Tags: email, lotus-notes, winforms-interop

I'd like to open a new email page, in Lotus Notes (I know I know, I hate it too...) from a WinForm (.NET) application. Right now, I have found [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/domino-msnet/) that uses Interop.Domino.dll very useful. I adapted it a little and it works. Unfortunately, I don't want the email to be sent. I just need to open a new mail window with the body I give it, but no "To adress"...

I know Notes question don't have a high reply rate over here, but I give it a try anyway.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Notes clients greater than version 6, there is support for a Notes:\ URL scheme to launch documents.  You can construct a URL dynamically in .Net that points to the user's mail database and opens a new mail form.

http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/LotusNotes_notesURLs.html has more details, but essentially it is of the form Notes:\server\database\0\memo?OpenForm

Comment: I didn't fully tested it yet, but it definitely seems to be the way I want to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't just use a `mailto` call in your code? Assuming that Lotus Notes is the registered mail handler on the client system, you should be able to pass in the body attribute and wot-not…

Comment: That's what they actually use, but it got a limitation of about 150 char from what they told me.

Comment: I think the limit depends more on the browser: for example, many limit parameters to around 255 characters, so a mailto with a long body string can fail. I'm not aware of any specific limitations in the Lotus Notes mail client with regards mailto, but they could well exist of course.

Answer (score 0):

The Lotus Domino Objects (Interop.Domino.dll) don't have access to the Notes UI. You would need to use the deprecated, late-bound Lotus Notes Automation classes. Warning: they're crashy, which is one of the reasons they've been deprecated for more than ten years (since the release of Lotus Notes and Domino R5.0.2c).

Comment: Since they're crashy, I'll try something else. Thanks for the tip and the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did use the mailto. Here the code :

> Public Shared Sub OuvrirNouveauMessage(ByVal destinataire As String, ByVal sujet As String, ByVal corpsCourriel As String)

```
        Dim sFile As String = "mailto:" & destinataire & _
                              "?subject=" & sujet & _
                              "?body=" & corpsCourriel

        If sFile.Length > 2050 Then
            sFile = sFile.Substring(0, 2050)
        End If

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sFile)

    End Sub
```

Comment: The 2050 limitations had been tested with Lotus Notes 8.5 and IE7. Other versions has smaller tolerance. In our old version, only 255 could be used. Donno if it was caused by browser or Notes though...